# Why is William Bell still alive?

Tags: fringe

Near the end of Season 4, Episode 19 of Fringe, we could see William Bell trapped in amber.

How could he be alive? Wasn't he supposed to be dead, even in the new time-line?

Comment: Knowing Fringe, we are *supposed* to be confused by this, and will get the answer 3 or 4 episodes from now. :/

Comment: In addition to the answer below, don't forget there's also two universes in the new timeline.

Comment: Although is not major, the title of the question is, in itself, a spoiler...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the old timeline, Bell sacrificed himself to get Peter and (undercover) Fauxlivia back Over Here at the end of Olivia's attempted rescue mission to retrieve Peter.  Since we know there were changes to the history around Fauxlivia's mission to infiltrate Olivia's life, it's not unreasonable to think Bell no longer sacrificed himself in this new timeline.  The changes around Fauxlivia's mission already resulted in alt-Broyles being alive again.

Comment: Walter mention Bell (Belly under the nickname of *Belly*), several times during season 4. I was under the impression he was death, but it's true that his death was never mentioned.

Comment: Bell being alive could also explain where Jones was getting his support in the new timeline.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Haha, nice prediction.

Comment: but why did Walter said on season 4 "its Belly he is still alive nina!" or something like that, so my question is why did they think that Bell was dead? Fringe is confusing cause so many things happen and i cant remember everything xD and i get lost im sure thats what happened with people that stopped watching the show and thats why they get low rating :c im still a big fan tho

Comment: in the new timeline Bell faked his own death (car accident, I think), presumably in order to work on creating his own universe. I think  that part is actually similar to his faking his own death in the original timeline, but then it was to go "over there" to fight the shapeshifters.